# Settings vs System Settings

Tags: gnome, system-settings

To be able to access my online Google Drive folder from Ubuntu, I installed two GNOME packages:

sudo apt install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts

Now if I open the Dash and write "settings", I see two different icons: "Settings" and "System Settings". It is not possible to open both of them at the same time, so I assume that "Settings" was meant to replace "System Settings" (after installing the two GNOME packages).

Is there any way to delete "System Settings", so that only "Settings" remain?

Comment: If you landed here from a Google search and just wanted to eliminate the seemingly duplicate functions see my answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056946/225694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak these via the `.desktop` files (mostly) in the `/usr/share/applications/` folder and you need Root/Admin priviledges for this purpose.

For instance, if you're sure, they are duplicate and this is the one you don't want, you can open the file `unity-control-center.desktop` there, and -as a safer method- merely add the line `Hidden=true` and/or `NoDisplay=true` instead of deleting it.

Comment: I am a linux beginner and I would rather not do anything requiring root/admin (and I don't even understand what you wrote). I thought that there could be some easy way to fix this issue as certainly many users need to access their google drive files. If there is no easy way to fix this then I would rather ignore it.

Comment: There's no way to make such system modifications without using admin powers (this is so also in windoze nowadays - they're learning) and you can either choose leaving them or as a shortcut open **Terminal** app, enter `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/unity-control-center.desktop` followed by your password when prompted, and then make it invisible as above.

Comment: And as a Linux beginner if you find that Gnome's solution to the lack of an official Google Drive client app for Linux is short of your expectations, you can also try this: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive And if you're satisfied, you can get rid of those two packages ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete unity-control-center (the default system settings) by using 
`sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center` Careful though, this could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After an upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 I too had both "Settings" and "System Settings" showing up on my menu. I determined what programs they actually were by launching them one at a time and checking the output of `ps -ax` I found that on my system, "Settings" corresponded to `gnome-control-center` and "System Settings" corresponded to `unity-control-center` in my case I wasn't using gnome online accounts so I removed `gnome-control-center` .

In your specific case you'd think you'd want to remove the other one(`unity-control-center`) as indicated by [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/848593/225694) **I wouldn't recommend it** though as on my system doing so resulted in strange results like being unable to get screen information from displays and it also removes the [ubuntu-desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop) package. If it's not too annoying, **I would recommend that you just ignore it** as you could easily end up missing several [packages you've come to depend on that are dependencies of the ubuntu-desktop meta package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop) that are not [dependencies of the gnome-control-center package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome-control-center) the next time you did a `sudo apt autoremove`