# settings and system settings

Tags: settings, system-settings

I have two icons in 'start' menu.
How can I delete one of them and which one should I delete?

[image]

Comment: Why delete any of them? Sounds like a bad idea. What if you need it later?

Comment: judging by the picture .. they probably both point to the same app .. i would launch each one .. or make desktop shortcuts to both and then edit the shortcut and see if they both point to the same app .. if so ... lol I hate Unity so i have no idea how to delete one of them :D lol

Comment: Post the output of `grep -rE '^Exec=unity-control-center( --overview|$)' /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications`. This will search through the two folders for application launchers and find ones that open the Unity Control Center (AKA System Settings).

Comment: See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056946/225694)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output of:

```
grep -rE '^Exec=unity-control-center( --overview|$)' 
    /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications
```

[image]